# Add image overlay to specific category thumbnails - wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, thumbnails, categories

Aloha Stack overflow! so ive been trying many ways to add an image overlay to specific a category thumbnails in wordpress.

Pretty much i just want a banner image that lays diagonal across all the thumbnails of one particular category. I dont need this banner to show on any other category but that one.

Ive tried a couple of banner plugins etc, but none of them are able too add the banner overlay only to the one worpress category thumbnails.

Any tips on how i can go about implementing this?

I had this feature on my old theme, but now ive upgraded i cant work out how to get the same here.

I can provide any css or code needed. Would love to hear from some amazing folks on this one, stackoverflow never lets me down

Answer (score 0):

Try the following concept:

```css
.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: url('http://placehold.it/200/000');
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerard, but how do i limit this to only one of the 20 categories i have on the site? so much thanks for your help

Comment: Can the category be recognized in the produced page?

Comment: im not sure... i want it to appear on the main feed and the single post page? Thanks Gerard